# Best way to notify parent process from child

Tags: python, twisted

I have a Python twisted application whose work is to execute os processes, monitor their life cycle and collect their logs and exit status.
Now I wanted to add a feature which allows child process to notify about it's progress(e.g 50% complete) to parent. How can I enable this communication in best way?
I thought of a rest endpoint in parent where child posts.
Is there any other better way to enable this communication between parent process and child(can be any is process)?

PS: application is written in twisted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [os.pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe) or [multiprocessing.pipe and queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) to communicate between child and parent processes. You can also use [semaphores](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore).

You could also use RabitMQ to do IPC or just [read a file that's being written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290292/read-from-a-log-file-as-its-being-written-using-python).