# Can you compare one file with fixed list of words with one file which is being updated with words every 10 seconds in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f1 = open("C:/Users/user/Documents/intro.txt", "r")  
f2 = open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/intro1.txt", "r")  
  
i = 0
  
for line1 in f1:
    i += 1
      
    for line2 in f2:
          
        
        if line1 == line2:  
            print("Line ", i, ": IDENTICAL")       
        else:
            print("Line ", i, ":")
            print("\tFile 1:", line1, end='')
            print("\tFile 2:", line2, end='')
        break
f1.close()                                       
f2.close()
```

Can this method be used to compare them?
I tried alot of methods but i dont see any solutions
If anyone could help me that would be great!
I am fairly new to python

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290292/read-from-a-log-file-as-its-being-written-using-python) thread about writing to a file as it's being written to. As for the static file, you could simply just store the data in some sort of data structure (like a `list`) and use that for comparison :)

Comment: Do you need to compare the files line by line and find out all different lines.. or to compare two files whole?  I guess in the last case you can simply make and compare hashes of the files with <hashlib>.

Comment: @Bohdan Yes exactly files lines need to be compared line by line so if there is a different line in the the file that is  being constantly updated then it should be exported to a different file saying these lines are different

Comment: @gmdev Yes i am looking into to the thread you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The above code would compare every line in the file to every line in the other file for each line. You would want to compare them by the same index.

```
with open("C:/Users/user/Documents/intro.txt", "r") as f1:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()

with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/intro1.txt", "r") as f2:
    lines2 = f2.readlines()

length1 = len(lines1)
length2 = len(lines2)

if length1 == length2:
    for i in range(length1):
        line1 = lines1[i]
        line2 = lines2[i]

        if lines1[i] == lines2[i]:
            print("Line ", i, ": IDENTICAL")
        else:
            print("Line ", i, ":")
            print("\tFile 1:", line1, end='')
            print("\tFile 2:", line2, end='')
            break
else:
    print("Unequal length: ", length1, " ", length2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my upper comment, here is the code to easy make hash for a file:

```
import hashlib

def hash_file(filename):
   """"This function returns the SHA-1 hash
   of the file passed into it"""

   # make a hash object
   h = hashlib.sha1()

   # open file for reading in binary mode
   with open(filename,'rb') as file:

       # loop till the end of the file
       chunk = 0
       while chunk != b'':
           # read only 1024 bytes at a time
           chunk = file.read(1024)
           h.update(chunk)

   # return the hex representation of digest
   return h.hexdigest()
```